# Postfix, forwarding and SPF

Tags: gmail, postfix-mta, spf

Ive been implementing a forwarding agent with dovecot+postfix, everything goes fine, public IP is AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA

xxxxxx.com.ar has this SPF record
"v=spf1 mx AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA -all"

MX points to same AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA IP, but google (i also receive a lot less but same reports from Zoho Mail) is bothering with false? DMARC rejections:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <feedback>
      <report_metadata>
        <org_name>google.com</org_name>
        <email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>
        <extra_contact_info>https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580</extra_contact_info>
        <report_id>733545798811562331</report_id>
        <date_range>
          <begin>1616544000</begin>
          <end>1616630399</end>
        </date_range>
      </report_metadata>
      <policy_published>
        <domain>xxxxxx.com.ar</domain>
        <adkim>r</adkim>
        <aspf>r</aspf>
        <p>reject</p>
        <sp>reject</sp>
        <pct>100</pct>
      </policy_published>
      <record>
        <row>
          <source_ip>AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA</source_ip>
          <count>4</count>
          <policy_evaluated>
            <disposition>none</disposition>
            <dkim>pass</dkim>
            **<spf>fail</spf>**
          </policy_evaluated>
        </row>
        <identifiers>
          <header_from>xxxxxx.com.ar</header_from>
        </identifiers>
        <auth_results>
          <dkim>
            <domain>xxxxxx.com.ar</domain>
            <result>pass</result>
            <selector>default</selector>
          </dkim>
          <spf>
            <domain>mail.minte.com.ar</domain>
            <result>pass</result>
          </spf>
        </auth_results>
      </record>
    </feedback>
```

Weirdest thing: look how google reads a valid email from this domain:

[image: SPF and valid DKIM]

any help will be greatly appreciated, im afraid google will end marking AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA as SPAMMER

thanks !!

Comment: It might be an editing mistake, but that SPF is not valid. It should be `v=spf1 ip4:AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA mx -all`. It's better to put literal IPs first as it saves lookups by the receiver. Another issue is that sometimes `-all` can break DMARC; better to use `~all` and have DMARC do the rejection rather than SPF alone.

Comment: Trying ! Will keep updated, thanks !

Comment: Thanks !! It seems to be solved, no more "false" DMARC bounces. But I can not mark your answer as correct, as it was a comment. Thank you again !

Comment: That’s cool. I’ll repost it as an answer

Comment: Unfortunately, "false" DMARC emails appeared today. Same exact message :( Do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: Nothing else :( ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zoho Support Team said, the problem is with SPF alignment.

> On analyzing the attached DMARC report, we see that email sent using the source IP "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" had passed the SPF & DKIM authentication.
> Please be informed that DMARC policy is evaluated based on "SPF authentication & SPF Alignment" or "DKIM authentication & DKIM Alignment".
> In the below attached report, we see the SPF Authentication is passed but SPF alignment fails as the From domain "client.com.ar" & Return Path domain "server.com" are different and that's the reason its mentioned as fail.
> To know more about DMARC policy,
> https://postmarkapp.com/guides/dmarc#how-does-dmarc-work

This is due to postfix aplying SRS, so reply-to is @forwarder-domain.com so breaks SPF alignment with the sender domain.

Seems unsolvable.